# User-select not working on a:visited

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a Math website, and it has some exercises on it with solutions on the bottom of the page. I want to make so solutions are hidden when the user scrolls by them, and needs to click on the block for it to show the answer. I want to achieve this using only css and html. Here's what I have made so far:

### HTML:

```
<div class="solution s1">
  <a href="#s1">2+2=4</a>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.solution {
  width:80%;
  margin:25px auto;
}

.solution a:visited{
  color:black;
  background-color:white;
  user-select:text;
}

.solution a{
  background-color:#49FF59;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  padding:25px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#49FF59;
  text-decoration:none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

This code works great, except for the user-select. I want it so that the user can't copy the solution, before the block is clicked on. But the `a:visited` won't apply the `user-select:text;` I have tried to add more classes, but i wasn't able too fix it. Keep in mind most of the CSS is for asterisk.

Comment: With a set up like this you do realize that anyone can view source or use a simple browser inspector to see the solution, right?

Comment: Yes I do realize so, but its targeted towards 1-4th graders, and i dont belive them to be that clever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct, the approach you're trying to take is to prevent someone from doing a select all and seeing the solutions on screen due to the text being highlighted.

If that's the case there are better style properties to use for this, particularly `visibility` or `display`.

For example you can use `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` to hide the solution until a specific condition is met.

I'd also advise against using `:visited` for something like this, unless you have specific urls for each question that you plan to override (if you use href='#') for everything, then once you click one, they are all 'visited'). You're going to also have struggles with browser caches when using `:visited`.

As an example, you could alter your container to be the clickable element, and hide your content using `visibility`, then show the answer on the `:active` state as opposed to the `:visited` state.  This will show the answer while the mouse button is pressed.  Under normal circumstances the text isn't selectable because it's hidden. If you want to keep it shown after a click but not use `:visited` you'll need a javascript solution.

Worth stating that this solution **will not hide answers in the source code**, but as you mentioned above that is not a concern for you.

```css
.solution {
  width:80%;
  margin:25px auto;
  background-color:#49FF59;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  padding:25px;
  text-align:center;
}

.solution:active {
  color:black;
  background-color:white;
  user-select:text;
}

.solution:active a {
  color:black;
  background-color:white;
  visibility:visible;
}

.solution a{
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="solution s1">
  <a href="#s1">2+2=4</a>
</div>
```